# Jasper reports PDF tagging

Tags: pdf-generation, jasper-reports, accessibility

I have heard that you can tag PDF documents generated using Jasper Reports but I haven't found any examples of how to do it.
Does anyone here have an example of how you would tag a PDF document?

I'm interested in tagging them to create accessible PDFs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I'd like to apologize since I cannot answer this question the right way.

Anyway I'm looking for an answer to the same exact question and I can only collect a couple of useful links to keep on searching:

http://jasperforge.org/plugins/espforum/view.php?group_id=102&forumid=103&topicid=72177

http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/export/JRPdfExporterTagHelper.html

Hope it helps to keep the question alive and bring others experiences here.

Answer (score 2):

If you place the following code in the JRXML file:

```
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.pdf.tagged" value="true"/>
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.pdf.tag.language" value="EN-US"/>
```

...then the PDF should be tagged when generated.  At least, this is what I've found as of JasperReports 4.0.1.  I can't speak for earlier versions.

EDIT: On a sidenote, this is also a way to get Tooltips to show on images, which can be used as alt text for the image, with regard to accessibility.

Answer (score 0):

From Jasper Reports sources, there is a demo/samples folder, the Tabular report is a tagged pdf report.

iReport has tips on how to use the available tags (table, tr, td, h1, h2, h3, etc). Click on Properties Expressions and then hit 'Add' you'll see the tips below the property/value fields.